# I have Create Script for checking if the ticket number is already inserting or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting an issue, that when I submit the form it adds ticket number + 1 but script does not check the number which is change on page load. what is the solution that the script works without any action like KEYUP?

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#ticket_no').keyup(function(){  
       var ticket_num = $(this).val();  
       if(ticket_num != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"search.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{ticket_num:ticket_num},  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      $('#ticket_no').css("border-color", "green");  
                      $('#ticket_error').html(data);
                 }
            });  
       }  
        else{
            $('#ticket_no').css("border-color", "red");                
        }
  }); }); </script>
```

Comment: I'm not getting what your asking. But could it be that you want to prevent the default behaviour of your form?

Comment: i have developed script for airline tickets. in which at a time they issues 100 of ticets with series like 1 to 100. in this application there is feild which check weather the tickets number is already inserted or not. if not submit form insert ticket number and  add + 1 on ticket number  and show on same feild. For Example . ticket number is 1  + 1 = 2. when ticket number change  script not work. i have to erase and re write. then script work.